# regular expression - account for match and not match partial

Tags: python, regex

I have a block of html code in a file. I have a pattern I'm using in a very large html file. I'm looking for all text with **ba and sqft** However, there are entries that do not have the sqft and I'd like to capture that as 0.  Also in my code it captures the ba but in the demo it doesn't.

REGEX ([0-9]+) ba<[\S\s]*?>(.*) sqft

demo: https://regex101.com/r/Nr6lEo/1

```
desire: '2, 1,596', '4, 0', '2, 2,376'
actual: '2, 1,596', '2, 2,376'
```

Comment: If the block has no `sqft` sometimes, I think the best way (with regex) is to use an optional group, but make sure you do not match over `ba` and `sqft`, see `([0-9]+) ba<(?:(?:(?! ba| sqft)[\S\s])*?>(.*) sqft)?` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/3AYrKc/1). You will still need some code to assign the default `0` when `sqft` is missing.

Comment: Do you have a link to the full html? (This task might be trivial using `lxml`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access only to the corrupt HTML like the one you showed in the regex demo, you can use

```
\b(\d+)\s*ba<(?:\S*(?:\s(?!ba<|sqft<)\S*)*>(\d[,.\d]*)\s*sqft\b)?
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3AYrKc/3). Note you will need to use some code to assign the default `0` when `sqft` part is missing because the regex itself cannot set default values, it only returns the text that exists in the string.

The regex is this long to avoid too much backtracking (since the file is long). It matches

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(\d+)` - Group 1: one or more digits
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `ba<` - `ba<` string
- `(?:\S*(?:\s(?!ba<|sqft<)\S*)*>(\d[,.\d]*)\s*sqft\b)?` - an optional sequence of:

  - `\S*` - zero or more non-whitespaces
  - `(?:\s(?!ba<|sqft<)\S*)*` - zero or more sequences of a whitespace that is not immediately followed with `ba<` and `sqft<` and then any zero or more non-whitespace chars
  - `>` - a `>` char
  - `(\d[,.\d]*)` - Group 2: a digit and then zero or more digits, `.` or `,` chars
  - `\s*sqft\b`  - zero or more whitespaces, `sqft` and a word boundary.

So, the [Python code](https://ideone.com/yV0Sxo) might look like

```py
import re
html = """1.45;"  >1234 St1 St</p> <p class=3D"highlight-address" styl=\ne=3D"margin: 0; font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif; text-decoration: non=\ne; color: #323232; font-weight: 500; font-size: 13px; line-height: 1.45;"  =\n>City, ST 12345</p><p class=3D"highlight-specs" style=3D"margin: 0; fo=\nnt-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif; text-decoration: none; color: #323232;=\n font-weight: 500; font-size: 13px; line-height: 1.45;"><span style=3D"disp=\nlay: inline-block;">4 bd</span><span style=3D"display: inline-block;">&nbsp=\n;=E2=80=A2&nbsp;</span><span style=3D"display: inline-block;">2 ba</span><s=\npan style=3D"display: inline-block;">&nbsp;=E2=80=A2&nbsp;</span><span styl=\ne=3D"display: inline-block;">1,596 sqft</span></p><p class=3D"highlight-spe=\ncs" style=3D"margin: 0; font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif; textdecorati=\n\n1.45;"  >5678 St2 Rd</p> <p class=3D"highlight-address" sty=\nle=3D"margin: 0; font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif; text-decoration: no=\nne; color: #323232; font-weight: 500; font-size: 13px; line-height: 1.45;" =\n >City2, ST 6789</p><p class=3D"highlight-specs" style=3D"margin: 0=\n; font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif; text-decoration: none; color: #323=\n232; font-weight: 500; font-size: 13px; line-height: 1.45;"><span style=3D"=\ndisplay: inline-block;">4 bd</span><span style=3D"display: inline-block;">&=\nnbsp;=E2=80=A2&nbsp;</span><span style=3D"display: inline-block;">4 ba</spa=\nn></p><p class=3D"highlight-specs" style=3D"margin: 0; font-family: 'Montse=\nrrat', sans-serif; textdecoration: none; color: #323232; font-weight: 500; =\n\n1.45;"  >91011 St3 Rd</p> <p class=3D"highlight-address" style=\n=3D"margin: 0; font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif; text-decoration: none=\n; color: #323232; font-weight: 500; font-size: 13px; line-height: 1.45;"  >=\nCity2, ST 10111</p><p class=3D"highlight-specs" style=3D"margi=\nn: 0; font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif; text-decoration: none; color: =\n#323232; font-weight: 500; font-size: 13px; line-height: 1.45;"><span style=\n=3D"display: inline-block;">4 bd</span><span style=3D"display: inline-block=\n;">&nbsp;=E2=80=A2&nbsp;</span><span style=3D"display: inline-block;">2 ba<=\n/span><span style=3D"display: inline-block;">&nbsp;=E2=80=A2&nbsp;</span><s=\npan style=3D"display: inline-block;">2,376 sqft</span></p><p class=3D"highl=\night-specs" style=3D"margin: 0; font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif; text="""
pattern = r"\b(\d+)\s*ba<(?:\S*(?:\s(?!ba<|sqft<)\S*)*>(\d[,.\d]*)\s*sqft\b)?"
matches = re.findall(pattern, html)
for ba,sqft in matches:
    if not sqft:
        sqft = "0"
    print(f"{ba}, {sqft}")
```

Output:

```
2, 1,596
4, 0
2, 2,376
```